# На MacOS пакетный менеджер Conan не находит команды терминала

Tags: python, c++, macos, conan, github-actions

При сборке проекта под MacOS на github actions вываливается ошибка:

```
/Users/runner/work/_temp/75a367ce-c675-46e9-bd06-8ef5b2a5a652.sh: line 4: conan: command not found
```

Хотя Conan установлен успешно:

```
Collecting conan Downloading conan-1.45.0.tar.gz (717 kB)
```

Поискав ответы, пишут что надо установить переменную $PATH или перезапустить терминал.
Вопрос, как это сделать и где найти каталог установки.

Comment: а причем здесь python, простите?

Comment: Потому, что через pip установлено